# SAPUI5 OData v2: delete row from m.Table

Tags: odata, sapui5

I know already from SAPUI5 API reference that I can delete a row from a bound m.Table based on Odata v2 model using the remove method like:

oModel.remove("/Products(999)", {success: mySuccessHandler, error: myErrorHandler});

According to the SAPUI5 docu, this will create a DELETE request to backend server. How can I prevent from immediately sending the DELETE request to backend server in order to control the confirmation to backend by explicitely pressing a SUBMIT button first (calling there the oModel.submitChanges method)? Is operation mode sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode.Client useful for deletions or does this mode control changed and inserted records into the OData model only?

Yours
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

You can just pop a confirmation dialog before calling the `oModel.remove` method.

[sap.m.sample.DialogConfirm](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DialogConfirm/preview)

Comment: Thanks, but I like to insert, delete and change rows in the client and then I like to confirm the changes by submitChanges and not to call a dialog before each row deletion. In other words, editing , inserting and deleting grid rows before sending any changes to backend server and without individual confirmations in dialogs. This should be possible.